# Getting post id in WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to execute the query in WordPress to retrieve the last post from featured category, then check for its custom field and show an image stored in it.
Well, my code is not working for some reason.Can you spot any error there? Or point me in the right direction?

```
<?php $featured = new WP_Query('showposts=1&category_name=featured'); ?>
<?php if($featured->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while($featured->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image3', true); ?>"></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will do what you expecting

```
$args['category_name']='featured'; // posts from particular category
$args['orderby']='date'; //to get latest post
$args['order']='DESC';
$args['numberposts']='1';// to get only one post from post list

$featured = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: @Alex:No, you just need array with right key and values.  $args = **array(
"category_name"=>"featured",
"orderby"=>"date",
"order"=>"DESC",
"numberposts"=>"1"
);**  this one also valid . is my query works for you